# Mongoid order_by with a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Ok, this one is driving me nuts.

I have a one to one relationship.  company has_one company_statistic and company statistic belongs to company.

I am trying to use order_by on the relationship.  For example I can do:

```
CompanyStatistic.order_by(:company_id, :desc)
```

What I am trying to do is order_by a field on company like:

```
CompanyStatistic.order_by(:company.name, :desc)
```

Is there any way to do this at all in mongoid?

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

```
@company = CompanyStatistic.order_by(:company_id.desc)
```

or,

```
@company = CompanyStatistic.desc(:company_name)
```

Comment: It would more useful if you add why this piece of code works.

Comment: This doesn't order by the company name.

Comment: What makes you think `CompanyStatistic` has a `company_name` field?

Comment: @muistooshort You are correct, there is not a company_name field.  I guess that would be one option; add that field.  It still seems like this should be doable with a relationship.

Comment: @muistooshort any idea how to do sorting for associated columns?

Comment: @PoojaMane In MongoDB? No idea, I haven't used MongoDB for years.

Comment: @muistooshort yes in MongoDB. OK Thank you.